# Count only the id's which are not counted in earlier group

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
Select    GroupId,
          count(distinct GroupProgramYearParticipantID)as [ChildAddedprior]  
from      #temp1 
Where     (MonthFlag = '1') 
and       (ParticipantTypeName = 'child')  
and       (GroupProgramYearParticipantID not in 
          (Select  distinct GroupProgramYearParticipantID 
           from    #temp1 t 
           Where   (t.MonthFlag = '2') 
           and     (t.ParticipantTypeName = 'child') 
           and     t.GroupId = GroupId)) 
group by  groupId
```

If groupID 1 has GroupProgramYearParticipantID's 1,2,2,3,4,4
and groupID 2 has GroupProgramYearParticipantID's 2,4,4,5,5,6,7

The above query returns

```
GroupID-1 ChildAddedprior- 4( which takes 1,2,3,4)
DroupID-2 ChildAddedPrior- 5(which includes 2,4,5,6,7)
```

But what I want is

```
GroupID-1 ChildAddedprior- 4 (which takes 1,2,3,4)
DroupID-2 ChildAddedPrior- 3 (which includes 5,6,7)(this doesn't include 2,4 which are counted earlier).
```

Help is really appreciated

Comment: Heya, welcome to SO! A question usually gets most of its attention during the first few minutes after it's originally posted, so be sure to use the preview and markdown help to make it as readable, understandable, and complete as possible (to get the most out of it).

Comment: actually there is no such possibility in general way, try to answer question "how sql server will understand that groupid2 should exclude data from groupid1, maybe vice versa?"

Comment: If not a general way. Is there anyway to do this?

Comment: Are there just two groupIds?

Comment: Not just two there can be many. Just mentioned 2 for example.

Comment: Are groupids integer only or that is just in the example? How would I know the ordering of groupids?

Comment: @user2871694 yes, if you answer to my question - how you will distinguish between groups

Comment: @Anup Yes they are integer. You can order by groupID.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT GroupID, COUNT(Distinct GroupParticipantID) AS CNT 
FROM #Temp1 A
WHERE A.GroupParticipantID NOT IN
(
SELECT GroupParticipantID 
  FROM #Temp1 B
  WHERE A.GroupID > B.GroupID
)
Group BY GroupID
```

**[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/b95ae/5)**

Answer (score 0):

You could use 2 queries to achieve that.

1. Select the first group's ids into a temp table.
2. When selecting the second group, don't select ids that exist in the temp table.

Alternatively,  you can take the results of your query (ids) and use common table expressions to count groups recursively starting from the first one and excluding items from groups you already counted.

Comment: This doesn't fit as my number of groups is not just 2.

Comment: Ok, see my alternative way

Answer (score 0):

Does this cover your requirement?

```
select GroupId, count(GPYPId) [Count]
from (
    select distinct min(GroupId) GroupId, GroupProgramYearParticipantID GPYPId
    from #temp1
    group by GroupProgramYearParticipantID
) tblA
group by GroupId;
```

It doesn't take into consideration the MonthFlag.